# Is it possible to pass data from a flutter android app to a VeriFone device?

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, verifone

I'm trying to know how to pass data from a Flutter app to a device such as a VeriFone one.

The data will NOT be for a payment, it is simply a list of orders that includes products from a supermarket.

Example:

When the user checks out after choosing the products they want to buy, the order details get transferred/passed to the VeriFone device where it is printed out from the device so the vendor can begin preparing the order ( Like a receipt ).

Also, the user will not be in the same place as the VeriFone device, so passing the data cannot be done through WiFi or Bluetooth.